# How do I compile the documents which comes with the Bot Builder SDK?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to understand the Node.js SDK of MS Bot builder framework. When I try to run the cmd file I am getting the following error.

> D:\RND\MS_Bot_builder\BotBuilder\Node\docs>build-docs.cmd
>
> **[COMPILING DOCS]**
>
> 'typedoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Does anyone have idea how to get this compiled into readable format?

---

**Update:** Read open issue on [`typedoc`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/178) regarding this & found information like directory structure that contains spaces on Windows will cause this error. But I have already tried this as you see the path mentioned does not contain any spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `typedoc` NPM module globally with `npm install -g typedoc`. Then run the `.cmd` file. If you open the `.cmd` file with a text editor, you can see it contains a long typedoc command.